# Jooq: Extract value from SortField

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I am doing pagination with Jooq. Data is ordered by multiple fields, one of them is a custom function on field. For example, I have a SortField like this:

```java
DSL.coalesce(TABLE.COLUMN, 0).asc()
```

The final SQL will look like:

```sql
SELECT a, b, c
FROM TABLE
WHERE condition
ORDER BY COLUMN_A ASC, coalesce(TABLE.COLUMN, 0) ASC
```

Now I want to get the value of last record on a page. It works with normal field when using

```java
record.getValue(field.getName())
```

But when it comes to my custom field, it throws an exception that says that

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field (coalesce) is not contained
>   in Row

Do we have any ways to get the value of above *coalesce* function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not specific to jOOQ. SQL simply works this way. The behaviour you got is natural because you did not select that expression:

```sql
SELECT a, b, c
FROM TABLE
WHERE condition
ORDER BY COLUMN_A ASC, coalesce(TABLE.COLUMN, 0) ASC
```

Will produce 3 columns: `a`, `b`, and `c`. Example:

```
a   b   c
------------
1   2   3
4   5   6
```

In that result, there's no column by the name "coalesce". If you want to have a column by the name "coalesce" or anything similar, you would need to project it. In jOOQ:

```java
Field<Integer> coalesce = DSL.coalesce(TABLE.COLUMN, 0);

for (Record record : DSL.using(configuration)
       .select(TABLE.A, TABLE.B, TABLE.C, coalesce)
       .from(TABLE)
       .where(condition)
       .orderBy(TABLE.A.asc(), coalesce.asc()))
    System.out.println(record.get(coalesce));
```